# Unable to delete triggers (google-apps-script)

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I appear to have triggers that I cannot delete in my Google Apps Script. I have a theory as to WHY I cannot delete them, but no clue how to fix the problem. These triggers were attached to a script bound to files on a separate Google account that were shared with me. I of course was able to edit and modify the script and such as I wanted while the files were shared. Since then though the Google account that was sharing the files with me was deleted and I think the triggers that are "frozen" are residues from those files from that account. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

[image: A screen grab of my "frozen" triggers"]

Comment: Can you copy the file, rename the copy and then start working with the copy as the official file?  I wouldn't delete the old file until you know the new one is working.

Comment: There isn't any file to copy. None of the files I have on my drive have those as triggers as far as I can tell. That's the issue. I believe the files that have the triggers ceased to exist when the other account was deleted. That's part of the reason why they cannot be deleted.

Comment: Check the Apps Script Issue tracker: [Apps Script Issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) and if it doesn't exist, add a new issue.

Answer (score 2):

Simple triggers can not be deleted from that window:
[See Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#errors_in_triggers)

Instead add this function to your script and run it:

```
function deleteTriggers() {
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to your Google account, then choosing "Account Settings" and then "Account permissions". You should be directed to a list that has every permission (apps and scripts). You may be able to find it there.

https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to find out more about the script's container document. 
You can check for edit URLs and for users. 
If the document was not bound to a container, you could access the sharing information from the menu.
If you are the last person to use the script, you could also copy the script and delete the original script - manually or as a document. But take care of any dependencies like script properties.

I wrote a short loop to log information about container Url and its viewers:

```
function containerFinder() {
  if (DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()) { 
    var document = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var editUrl = document.getUrl();
    var editors = document.getViewers();
    Logger.log("This Script belongs to a document.");
    Logger.log("Edit Url: " + editUrl);
    Logger.log("Editors: " + editors);
  }
  else if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var editUrl = spreadsheet.getUrl();
    var editors = spreadsheet.getEditors();
    Logger.log("This Script belongs to a spreadsheet.");
    Logger.log("Edit Url: " + editUrl);
    Logger.log("Editors: " + editors);
  }
  else if (FormApp.getActiveForm()){
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var editUrl = form.getEditUrl();
    var editors = form.getEditors();
    Logger.log("This Script belongs to a form.");
    Logger.log("Edit Url: " + editUrl);
    Logger.log("Editors: " + editors);
  }
  else {
    Logger.log("This Script does not seem to belong to any container.");
  }
}
```