# GAS: Send emails at random time

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to send random emails about 2-3 times a week to a recipient using google apps script. I know I can use event triggers to send emails at a given time, but is it possible to randomize the triggers? I thought of using `sleep()`, but the script cannot be put to sleep for longer than five minutes.

Comment: How about creating a clock trigger with random duration https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#methods

Comment: In a clock trigger the trigger is created once when you run it and fires continuously. It is not possible to generate a random trigger.

Comment: Use a normal trigger to invoke a function where you create a custom time trigger. Custom time trigger should be created in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ScriptApp.newTrigger` to create custom time triggers.

```
function createRandomTimeTrigger() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("function_you_wanna_call")
   .timeBased()
   .after(Math.random() * 60 * 1000)
   .create();
}
```

Change the argument for `after` function to better suit your requirements. Now you can use a normal time trigger to invoke this function and it'll take care of the rest

Make sure you [delete](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deletetriggertrigger) the trigger after execution. Otherwise script will get shutdown due to too many triggers

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750921/unable-to-delete-triggers-google-apps-script) on SO on how to delete triggers

Comment: @Riyafa Abdul Hameed: You also need to delete the triggers after the function finishes execution. I've updated the answer to include such changes.