# Why is my Google App Script running itself without triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a short 1 line script to generate a random integer so I can set it up to run with a trigger so that every time an integer is generated my other scripts using it as a reference will update instead of using a cached version.

The problem is it seems to be running by itself without triggers about once every 10 minutes or so and I don't know what is causing it.

This is the code:

```
function RandomInt()
{
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Player List").getRange('B1').setValue(Math.random());
}
```

It works perfectly except the part about it running by itself.

Edit:
So far I believe I have found out that triggers are per user (I did not know this and couldn't find anything about it, but it might just be common sense) So someone else may have a trigger set up for it because a decent amount of people use the sheet.
I ran the deleteTriggers() script Craig posted at [Unable to delete triggers (google-apps-script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750921/unable-to-delete-triggers-google-apps-script)
And have not noticed the script running by itself anymore. The value has been the same for the last 30 minutes instead of changing every 10.

Edit2: It seems it was alright at first it stopped updating itself but when I added a trigger to update once per hour it started updating it randomly at approximately every 10 minute intervals again.

Edit3: I have abandoned trying to figure out what is wrong and decided to do

```
function Update()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Player List").getRange('B1').setValue(new Date().getUTCHours());
}
```

This instead it works well with triggers and even if you set it to shorter intervals it doesn't change the value until the next hour.

Edit4: I have confirmed that the problem was created by someone elses triggers running to every 10 minutes, so the script should work fine, not sure how to close this.

Comment: To "close this" you could post an answer and accept it.