# How can I delete another person's trigger on a google apps script project?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

My coworker has left his position in my company, so I'm trying to avoid any problems with our scripts when his account got deleted.
I'm trying, without success, to delete his triggers on our apps scripts projects. I tried with my personal account, with a drive admin account and with [deleteTriggers()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750921/unable-to-delete-triggers-google-apps-script) function, and was unable to do with at all.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can't delete other's person triggers from your account.

Comment: When I was stuck with this challenge where I couldn't remove the triggers. I renamed the original triggered functions. Also, I created a dummy function so that the old triggers don't fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **can't** delete other person's triggers from your account. It is **highly recommended** to ask the domain admin to remove the triggers from this account.

However, here is an alternative/unethical plan B solution. You can “**force**” him/her to delete all the triggers attached to his/her account of the current project/s.

Put this code snippet into the scripts that his trigger is currently executing:

```
function deleteAllTriggers(){
  const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  triggers.forEach(function(trigger){
    try{
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
    } catch(e) {
      throw e.message;
    };
    Utilities.sleep(1000);
  });
```

When he/she executes this code snippet (via his current trigger), all the triggers attached to his/her account for the current project will be deleted.

**Restrictions:**

The script that he/she is currently running should have authorized the  scope for [deleteTrigger()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deleteTrigger(Trigger)).

Comment: Won't work if he/she hadn't authorized the scope needed (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`) for [deleteTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#deletetriggertrigger) before :)

Comment: @TheMaster but he has authorized the current function to run right ?

Comment: Yes. But there's no guarantee that current function included  scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`

Comment: @TheMaster I get it now. I edited my answer to include that. I didn't know that the trigger function was requiring a separate authorization. Thanks a lot ! Hopefully, it worked for the OP.

Comment: I was running a spreadsheet project, so when I added the "deleteTrigger()" function, it asked me to authorize it, so it all went well on first try (but it's nice to add it to the answer anyway)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me!
But it seems to work by magic... I added a line `console.log(JSON.stringify(trigger));` inside the try so I could see what it was doing. When it ran it logged: `Dec 15, 2023, 11:14:48 AM Debug {}`
And yet it did delete the trigger! WTF??

Comment: Good answer, this helped me quite a bit. The function provided is missing a closing `}` though.